# Running a callback in a Vue component and waiting for result before changing state

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue component called `aui-button` that is used like:

`<aui-button classes="btn-primary test-class" :callback="test">Test Button</aui-button>`

I'm trying to design the component to be able to run any given callback without the callback requiring any structural changes or special return values; basically, I want to just give it some code, and have it run it. I pass the callback as a prop and call it. Easy.

```
props: ['classes', 'callback'],
methods: {
        runCallback() {
            this.callback();
        }
    }
```

What I'm stuck on is how to change the state data of the button based on the callback given those constraints.

```
data: function() {
        return {
            loading: false
        }
    },
```

How can I change the value of a specific data value on the component after callback execution given that I'd like to have zero say over what the callback argument is doing? Ideally these have a wide array of uses, from API calls to simple value changes.

Comment: At first glance it isn't clear why you are using a `callback` prop rather than a Vue event. What do you mean by 'after callback execution'? Do you mean just the synchronous execution of the function or the completion of any asynchronous processes that the function may initiate? If you need to handle asynchronous actions then you'll either have to return a Promise from the callback or pass a `next` function (yet another level of callback) to the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another answer in response to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59164052/running-a-callback-in-a-vue-component-and-waiting-for-result-before-changing-sta/59164316?noredirect=1#comment104553881_59164316).  If you **really** wanted to implement it that way then there's nothing stopping you.

The problem is that the callback will be asynchronous (otherwise, what's the point of setting a `loading` state), so the component needs to be told when the asynchronous callback has completed.

You could define your callback functions so that they take a `done()` callback.

**AuiButton.vue**

```
  props: ['classes', 'callback'],
  data() { return { loading: false}},
  methods: {
    runCallback() {
      this.loading = true;
      this.callback(this.doneCallback);
    },
    doneCallback() {
      this.loading = false;
    },
  },
```

**Parent Component**

```
  <aui-button classes="btn-primary test-class" :callback="test">Test Button</aui-button>
...
  methods: {
    test(doneCallback) {
      doSometingAsync(someData, (error, result) => {
        doneCallback();
        // do something with result..
      })
    },
```

Perhaps a better solution is to use events, but give the `click` event a `done` callback:

**AuiButton.vue**

```
  props: ['classes'], // don't need to pass the callback as a prop anymore.
  data() { return { loading: false}},
  methods: {
    runCallback() {
      this.loading = true;
      this.$emit('click', this.doneCallback);
    },
    doneCallback() {
      this.loading = false;
    },
  },
```

**Parent Component**

```
  <aui-button classes="btn-primary test-class" @click="test">Test Button</aui-button>
...
  methods: {
    test(doneCallback) {
      doSometingAsync(someData, (error, result) => {
        doneCallback();
        // do something with result..
      })
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than pass a callback to your button component, it is recommended practice to make your component [`$emit`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) an event to the parent.  The parent can then run whatever code it wants in the event handler.

Then, you should pass a `loading` prop to your component to control its loading state. e.g:

**AuiButton.vue**

```
  <button :classes="classes" :disabled="loading" @click="$emit('click') ...>
...

  props: {
    classes: String,
    loading: {
       type: Boolean,
       default: false
    },
```

**Parent component**

```
  <aui-button classes="btn-primary test-class" :loading="loading" @click="buttonClick">
     Test Button
  </aui-button>

...

  data() { return {
    loading: false,
  } },
  methods: {
    buttonClick() {
      this.loading = true;
      doSometingAsync(someData, (error, result) => {
        this.loading = false;
        // do something with result..
      })
    },
```

Now your button component doesn't need to do anything clever - it's told whether it should be in the loading state and it tells its parent whenever it is clicked.

Comment: This is the approach that I would take, too. The button should be stateless and presentational.

Comment: Is it just bad practice to track state on the component? I was hoping to avoid having to track a bunch of state variables in my main Vue instance. Ideally, the callbacks progress would have set the loading state. Feels/felt much cleaner that way. From what I understand from this, I have to match the number of buttons with variables for state, which was one of the main things I was trying to avoid.

Comment: Not necessarily bad, but ideally (IMHO) you'd track the state globally (in Vuex), and try to keep the actual components light on any business logic. Usually if the button is initiating some request, it expects a response back too, so you could have all that data in a global state.

Comment: If the component is **completely** in control of the state then the state can and should be contained within the component.  However, in this case the parent is in control of the state, so the state should belong to the parent and be passed to the component as a prop.

Hopefully not all of these buttons are contained within your main Vue instance - they should be within sub-components.  Try to break your UI down in to logical components each with their own `loading` state and button child components.

Comment: The request I got was to make sure they can be used in a piecemeal fashion. You want a button, you tell the button what to do, it does it and tracks it's state during the process. It's part of a library of elements that are just fed data or (hopefully) a callback, and anyone on the team can just call aui-button, tell it what to do, and not worry about mucking around tracking its state via some other variable. That was the goal, at least. In my view, that does mean it's completely in control of it's state. It doesn't care what the method it runs does, it just runs it + sets state accordingly

Comment: Since I can't put code in comments, see my [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59165238/9614402) in response to your comment.